# After installing Admin Dashboard stuck at loader

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

It is my first time to install Magento ( esting on localhost xampp windows 10) After installation and login Admin, the dashboard page stuck at loader and not able to click anything on that page

Upon checking console there are many errors show, kindly let me know how to get rid of these

this is how Dashboard looks after admin login
[image: this is how Dashboard looks after admin login]

and here is the console log errors

> ```
> index):1 [Report Only] Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,700.less' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src getfirebug.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.
> ```

> ```
> 6[Report Only] Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".
> ```

> ```
> require.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> ```

```
mixins.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
6Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
magento-icon.svg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
mixins.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
requirejs-config.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at requirejs-config.js:18
    at requirejs-config.js:19
    at requirejs-config.js:643
(index):45 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at (index):45
(index):94 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):94
(index):145 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at (index):145
(index):377 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):377
launch-EN30eb7ffa064444f1b8b0368ef38fd3a9.min.js:2 [Report Only] Refused to connect to 'http://dpm.demdex.net/id?d_visid_ver=4.4.0&d_fieldgroup=AAM&d_rtbd=json&d_ver=2&d_orgid=8F99160E571FC0427F000101%40AdobeOrg&d_nsid=0&d_mid=29743719464296385161644608670132256639&d_blob=RKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y&ts=1593811159571' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

fireCORS @ launch-EN30eb7ffa064444f1b8b0368ef38fd3a9.min.js:2
(index):489 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at (index):489
(index):1 [Report Only] Refused to connect to 'https://dpm.demdex.net/id?d_visid_ver=4.4.0&d_fieldgroup=AAM&d_rtbd=json&d_ver=2&d_orgid=8F99160E571FC0427F000101%40AdobeOrg&d_nsid=0&d_mid=29743719464296385161644608670132256639&d_blob=RKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y&ts=1593811159571' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

(index):553 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):553
(index):608 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):608
(index):666 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):666
(index):689 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):689
(index):712 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):712
launch-EN30eb7ffa064444f1b8b0368ef38fd3a9.min.js:2 [Report Only] Refused to connect to 'http://dpm.demdex.net/id?d_visid_ver=4.4.0&d_fieldgroup=MC&d_rtbd=json&d_ver=2&d_orgid=8F99160E571FC0427F000101%40AdobeOrg&d_nsid=0&d_mid=29743719464296385161644608670132256639&d_blob=RKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y&ts=1593811160166' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

fireCORS @ launch-EN30eb7ffa064444f1b8b0368ef38fd3a9.min.js:2
(index):1 [Report Only] Refused to connect to 'https://dpm.demdex.net/id?d_visid_ver=4.4.0&d_fieldgroup=MC&d_rtbd=json&d_ver=2&d_orgid=8F99160E571FC0427F000101%40AdobeOrg&d_nsid=0&d_mid=29743719464296385161644608670132256639&d_blob=RKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y&ts=1593811160166' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

(index):1 A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://demdex.net/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
opensans-400.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
admin-icons.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-600.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 [Report Only] Refused to load the image 'http://cm.everesttech.net/cm/dd?d_uuid=30164682664402128881605921059494271379' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src widgets.magentocommerce.com www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com t.paypal.com www.paypal.com www.paypalobjects.com fpdbs.paypal.com fpdbs.sandbox.paypal.com *.vimeocdn.com s.ytimg.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

(index):1 [Report Only] Refused to load the image 'http://amcglobal.sc.omtrdc.net/b/ss/amc.global.prod,amc.mag.admin.prod/1/JS-2.15.0-LAR3/s53861047311763?AQB=1&ndh=1&pf=1&t=4%2F6%2F2020%201%3A19%3A20%206%20-240&mid=29743719464296385161644608670132256639&aamlh=6&ce=UTF-8&cdp=1&fpCookieDomainPeriods=1&g=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmagento%2Fshahzad%2Fadmin%2Fdashboard%2Findex%2Fkey%2Ff57af2165e459d9ee9c7af2716318b5901264fcfdfb186f035af1f4bca44a3bc%2F&r=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmagento%2Fshahzad%2Fadmin%2Findex%2Findex%2Fkey%2Fc0e9189525693d1b02511bd0ed89c5a42d...shboard&hierarchy=dashboard&solution.&name=magento&version=2.3.5-p1&mode=default&edition=Community%20Edition&.solution&env=production&.page&user.&id=997b2e516d3a99e309b33783f07e5efd93c569dbb7b35711fb741f9e6eb0b039bee2e059d2a5f90da63e2a931512ed4aa721e3f8b7627f42f6af8eed67d2ee95&language=en&accountType=admin&authSystem=magento&corpId=unknown&.user&.c&cc=USD&aamb=RKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y&s=1366x768&c=24&j=1.6&v=N&k=Y&bw=1366&bh=608&mcorgid=8F99160E571FC0427F000101%40AdobeOrg&AQE=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src widgets.magentocommerce.com www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com t.paypal.com www.paypal.com www.paypalobjects.com fpdbs.paypal.com fpdbs.sandbox.paypal.com *.vimeocdn.com s.ytimg.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

assets.adobedtm.com/:1 [Report Only] Refused to frame 'http://fast.amc.demdex.net/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net www.paypal.com www.sandbox.paypal.com".

assets.adobedtm.com/:1 [Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://fast.amc.demdex.net/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net www.paypal.com www.sandbox.paypal.com".

opensans-700.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-600.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-400.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
admin-icons.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 [Report Only] Refused to load the image 'https://cm.everesttech.net/cm/dd?d_uuid=30164682664402128881605921059494271379' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src widgets.magentocommerce.com www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com t.paypal.com www.paypal.com www.paypalobjects.com fpdbs.paypal.com fpdbs.sandbox.paypal.com *.vimeocdn.com s.ytimg.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

opensans-700.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 [Report Only] Refused to load the image 'https://dpm.demdex.net/ibs:dpid=411&dpuuid=XoT-7wAAAxKII6x_&d_uuid=30164682664402128881605921059494271379' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src widgets.magentocommerce.com www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com t.paypal.com www.paypal.com www.paypalobjects.com fpdbs.paypal.com fpdbs.sandbox.paypal.com *.vimeocdn.com s.ytimg.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

2(index):1 [Report Only] Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,700.less' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src getfirebug.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/iframe_handler.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/content.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try running

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Did you update the magento mode?

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

This sets magento to development mode, so you don't have to run the last command from above every time you change static files (Javascript, HTML, Images, etc.).

Comment: Please be aware that windows 10 is a "bad" platform for Magento 2. If you are using Windows build 2004 i recommend you to check out the "Windows Subsystem For Linux" Version 2 or a Virtual Machine with a Linux distro, as you can run a Linux Webserver on Windows 10 which is way easier to use with Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies and answer . Someone suggest me following solution and it works be so I decided to share with you as well

go to `app/etc/di.xml`
find the line

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

and Replace it with

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Then
Upgrade
Deploy
Reindex
Clean cache